# Partial loading a view in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to render a `ui:composition`, an xhtml file lazily on an ***ajax*** event.

The new `ui:composition` needs to be  rendered inside a panel or a div.

In rails i do it this way

```
render :partial => "file", :layout => :none
```

**EDIT**

Also there is a way of passing locals to the partial view in rails

```
    render :partial => "file", :layout => :none, :locals => {:some_object => @some_object}
```

How do i send an object to this *to be rendered view*.

I am using following code in my xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton id="selectButton" value="Add" title="Add User" type="submit"
                                 action="#{userBean.add}">
  <f:ajax render=":userLanding:addPanel"/>                     
</p:commandButton>
```

Inside my ManagedBean i have

```
public String add()
{
   return "user"; // i need to open user.xhtml page.
}
```

`<div id="addPanel">` or better a `<p:panelGroup layout="block" id="addPanel">`

`userBean#add()` is responsible for rendering the abc.xhtml, which needs to be rendered inside my ui container.

Currently its redirecting to the page(abc.xhtml) and not rendering inside the target panel/div.

What is the JSF way of doing such view loading?

**Edit 2:**

I also tried:

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <ui:include src = "user.jsf"
</h:panelGroup>
```

but the condition is: ui include should be on button click event only and the src file will be displayed inside panel(no navigation).

Answer (score 0):

The `<f:ajax>` is not supported in PrimeFaces `<p:xxx>` components. You should be using `<p:ajax>` instead, or in this particular case, just the PrimeFaces `UICommand` component's own `update` attribute.

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":userLanding:addPanel" />
```

You only need to make sure that the action method returns `null` or `void`, otherwise navigation will still take place.

Comment: Thnx for the response. In my userBean.add action i am returning a string or a view id. thats how page is getting redirected to that view. If i return void how do i load desired page?

Comment: Uh, that just happens by `update=":userLanding:addPanel"`, exactly as you asked.

Comment: i think there is some miss communication from my side. please see the updated question. how will `update` attribute know what page to load

Comment: Uh, it just updates whatever markup is represented by `:userLanding:addPanel`. You can put everything therein, also `<ui:include>` and so on. If you want to bring any dynamics therein, just use `rendered="#{bean.rendered}"`, or `<ui:include src="#{bean.include}">`, etc.

Comment: Ok. i understood your point. that means i need to know what page I will be rendering inside my panel/div a priory. i have tried this approach earlier. But the problem is initially i want to have an empty container. and on some event i want to load this container with an page. Do i need conditional rendering? whats the correct approach. i guess i am able to explain the things ;)

Comment: Looking at the comments I think you're looking for <ui:include /> so you can bring "a page" into the view. BalusC is correct that using rendered is the easiest way to achieve this. That's exactly how I would do it.